# Importing Worklight Modules

Tags: android, eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have imported the worklight 6.0 Location Services module in my Eclipse Juno and started working. At first I got the android-8 exception and rectified by clicking the properties and configuring android 4.4 to my android project. After I built and deployed my module I found an error stating:

> Failed to deploy the application to Worklight server: Worklight module
>   module_09_07_LocationServices was not successfully started. Full
>   details of the error are available from the Worklight Development
>   Server console.

And after that I had seen the Worklight Server Console and there are no errors in that and in the Worklight Console I can see the `NullPointerException. check logs.` at the start.

When I opened the logs I got the Event Details pop-up stating the

```
Message:java.lang.NullPointerException

Exceptiin Stack Trace:java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.wst.integ.LibertyDeployer.addApplicationToConfigXML(LibertyDeployer.java:162)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.wst.integ.LibertyDeployer.postPublish(LibertyDeployer.java:148)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.wst.integ.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:93)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.utils.WSTServers.deployWar(WSTServers.java:590)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.utils.WSTServers.deployWorklightProjectWar(WSTServers.java:564)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.AbstractWorklightWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate.startServer(AbstractWorklightWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate.java:78)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.AbstractWorklightWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate.access$000(AbstractWorklightWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate.java:38)
    at com.worklight.studio.plugin.launch.AbstractWorklightWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate$1.run(AbstractWorklightWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Answer (score 1):

hi the error just went of when i just opened a new workspace and imported the same project.

Comment: Hi You just are too fast before trying to solve the problem . You post it and you itself finds the solution.